Strapi Login Form Customization
I am trying to add a new field(for captcha) to my login form for the admin panel in Strapi(version 5.2.0). So far I have tried adding a custom plugin and also trying to inject a component to my login form, but I have failed since it seems that the login form doesn't have any injection zones to inject customized components. I saw a video for earlier versions of Strapi where you could write an entirely customized login screen but it's not working for the new version. I looked into the patching solution but it seems very unclean. Has anybody succeeded in adding a new field to the Strapi login form for the admin panel?
